# Scheme- Append isn't working the way

Tags: list, scheme, append

I can't get this to work out properly. It's supposed to take two lists of possibly varying lengths, and add the elements together into one list.

For example, (polyAdd '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3)) would yield (2 4 6 4).

This is my program as of now. I think it should work, but it is only printing out (2 4 6), which I dont understand.

Here's the program:

```
(define (polyAdd l ll)
  (let ((num (- (length l) (length ll))))
    (if (> num 0)
        (append ll (nzero num))
        (append l (nzero (- 0 num)))))
  (if (not (or (= (length l) 1) (= (length ll) 1)))
      (cons (+ (car l) (car ll)) (polyAdd (cdr l) (cdr ll)))
      (cons (+ (car l) (car ll)) '())))

(define (nzero n)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons 0 (nzero (- n 1)))))
```

Thanks Sylwester, I just add `(set! ll` before the append and that got it to work.

Comment: The result of `append` is never used. It does not mutate any values.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper function to handle the case, where the two polynomials are of the same length.

```
(define (poly-add/same-length xs ys)
  (if (null? xs) 
      '()
      (cons (+ (car xs) (car ys)) 
            (poly-add/same-length (cdr xs) (cdr ys)))))

(define (poly-add xs ys)
  (let ((num (- (length xs) (length ys))))
    (if (> num 0)
        (poly-add/same-length xs (append ys (nzero num)))
        (poly-add/same-length (append xs (nzero (- 0 num))) ys))))

(define (nzero n)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons 0 (nzero (- n 1)))))

(poly-add '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

### For the Binary Case

This sounds like it's a variant on a binary **map** that doesn't require the lists to be equal length, but rather uses the other list as a terminator when one becomes empty.  When viewed that way, there's actually no need to use **append** at all;  just return the **list1** if **list2** is empty (and vice versa):

```
(define (map2 f list1 list2)
  (cond
    ((null? list1) list2)
    ((null? list2) list1)
    (else (cons (f (car list1) (car list2))
                (map2 f (cdr list1) (cdr list2))))))
```

Then your polynomial addition function just becomes a call to **map2** with **+**:

```
(map2 + '(0 1 2) '(3 4 5 8))
;=> (3 5 7 8)
```

```
(define (add-polynomials p1 p2)
  (map2 + p1 p2))

(add-polynomials '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3))
;=> (2 3 6 4)
```

### For a More General Case

Now, the **+** function in Scheme actually handles any number of values.  It might be nice to make the polynomial addition function behave in the same way.  One way of doing this would be to keep using the non-empty lists to produce an arglist for the function.

```
(define (remove x lst)
  (cond 
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((eqv? x (car lst)) (remove x (cdr lst)))
    (else (cons (car lst) (remove x (cdr lst))))))

(define (map-varargs f list1 . more-lists)
  (let ((all-lists (remove '() (cons list1 more-lists))))
    (if (null? all-lists)
        '()
        (cons (apply f (map car all-lists))
              (apply map-varargs f (map cdr all-lists))))))
```

```
(map-varargs + '(0 1)
               '(2 3 4)
               '(5 6 7 8)))
;=> (7 10 11 8)
```

Another possible approach (for the case when the function being mapped can't accept a variable number of arguments) would be to implement one that uses some default value when one of the lists becomes empty.

### Remarks

Note the use of **null?** to check whether a list is empty or not.  While checking whether the length of a list of 0 is *semantically* equivalent, checking for null requires just one comparison, whereas computing the length of a list requires traversing the whole list.